# Is there a caching mechanism when using directly Linux VFS functions?

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, kvm, vfs

I'm building an application on top of KVM hypervisor where I access (thousand of times) a small database (3 mb) by calling directly Linux kernel VFS functions.

After building a stable prototype of my application, I want to optimise its access to the database (by adding a cache for example).
I know that by doing file operations from userspace, Linux uses Page cache to accelerate the application, is this true also when using VFS functions from kernel space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as I expect you know, VFS is an abstraction layer, the idea being that all file systems look the same no matter what their implementation details are.

VFS can therefore do some caching at the VFS level, and then there is a buffer cache for all block devices further down the layer cake.

Comment: I'm feeling that reading the database file a lot of times is making my application slow, reading it all at one and doing my computation takes a lot less time. Is there a mean to check that my application is hiting (or not) the cache each time it reads the file ?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, there are ways to drop at least some caches by writing to stuff in /proc, but trying to do tests with accesses after invalidation or not sounds a bit awkward, your problem is not one I've directly as such had to face before. Have you looked at 'perf', it's a great tool, and lets you drill down into the kernel and what it's doing, but it does work by sampling, so it has limitations. Good for helping to find where time is being spent though... Might or might not help you with this, regardless as to if it's an FS cache issue. An app local cache will always be fastest of course.

Comment: Just found 'cachestats'. It can print number of cached vs not cached pages for a file. Just tried it, seems to work, `cachestats /vmlinuz` showed `0/760 (0.0%)` then after `cat /vmlinuz>/dev/null` it was `760/760 (100.0%)` I guess you could try it on your file to see if it is allegedly cached...

Comment: I can't find this command, how to install it ? it is included in what package ?

Comment: For my debian Linux jessie distribution the 'cachestats' binary is found in the 'nocache' package, along with 'cachedel', which invalidates the page cache for a file. Both useful for your testing pleasure. Also 'nocache' but I'm a bit more dubious about that one.

Comment: I tested cachestats tool, and apparently my application is reading from a cache ;)